# High Frequency Heap

Tags: c#, .net

Can anyone explain me the CLR's "HighFrequencyHeap"?

Answer (score 12):

The high frequency heap is used to store commonly used internal data structures such as the method table of types. This can be verified using WinDbg/SOS as shown below.

It is also stated in the [SSCLI book](http://callvirt.net/blog/files/Shared%20Source%20CLI%202.0%20Internals.pdf) (p. 235).

Here's part of the output for `!eeheap`

```
--------------------------------------
Domain 1:          006428c0
LowFrequencyHeap:  00340000(2000:2000) Size: 0x2000 (8192) bytes.
HighFrequencyHeap: 00342000(8000:2000) Size: 0x2000 (8192) bytes.
StubHeap:          Size: 0x0 (0) bytes.
Virtual Call Stub Heap:
  IndcellHeap:     Size: 0x0 (0) bytes.
  LookupHeap:      Size: 0x0 (0) bytes.
  ResolveHeap:     Size: 0x0 (0) bytes.
  DispatchHeap:    Size: 0x0 (0) bytes.
  CacheEntryHeap:  Size: 0x0 (0) bytes.
Total size:        Size: 0x4000 (16384) bytes.
--------------------------------------
Jit code heap:
LoaderCodeHeap:    004e0000(10000:1000) Size: 0x1000 (4096) bytes.
Total size:        Size: 0x1000 (4096) bytes.
--------------------------------------
Module Thunk heaps:
Module 5ef21000: Size: 0x0 (0) bytes.
Module 00342e9c: Size: 0x0 (0) bytes.
Total size:              Size: 0x0 (0) bytes.
--------------------------------------
Module Lookup Table heaps:
Module 5ef21000: Size: 0x0 (0) bytes.
Module 00342e9c: Size: 0x0 (0) bytes.
Total size:              Size: 0x0 (0) bytes.
--------------------------------------
Total LoaderHeap size:   Size: 0x13000 (77824) bytes.
=======================================
Number of GC Heaps: 1
generation 0 starts at 0x02521018
generation 1 starts at 0x0252100c
generation 2 starts at 0x02521000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
02520000  02521000  0252e010  0xd010(53264)
Large object heap starts at 0x03521000
 segment     begin allocated  size
03520000  03521000  03523250  0x2250(8784)
Total Size:              Size: 0xf260 (62048) bytes.
------------------------------
GC Heap Size:            Size: 0xf260 (62048) bytes.
```

Notice the location of the high frequency heap and the garbage collected heaps. Here's the output for `!dumpobject` for a statically allocated instance of `Program`.

```
0:000> !dumpheap -type Program
 Address       MT     Size
0252b630 00343858       12     
total 0 objects
Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
00343858        1           12 TestBench2010.Program
Total 1 objects
0:000> !do 0252b630 
Name:        TestBench2010.Program
MethodTable: 00343858
EEClass:     0034154c
Size:        12(0xc) bytes
File:        C:\workspaces\TestBench2010\TestBench2010\bin\Debug\TestBench2010.exe
Fields:
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
00343858  4000001        4 ...Bench2010.Program  0   static 0252b630 p
0:000> !dumpheap -type Program
 Address       MT     Size
0252b630 00343858       12     
total 0 objects
Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
00343858        1           12 TestBench2010.Program
Total 1 objects
0:000> !do 0252b630 
Name:        TestBench2010.Program
MethodTable: 00343858
EEClass:     0034154c
Size:        12(0xc) bytes
File:        C:\workspaces\TestBench2010\TestBench2010\bin\Debug\TestBench2010.exe
Fields:
  MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
00343858  4000001        4 ...Bench2010.Program  0   static 0252b630 p
```

Notice the address for the static reference `p` in the type `Program`. It points to an address in the garbage collected heap. Also, notice the address of the Method Table. It points to an address in the high frequency heap.

Answer (score 2):

> Every static variable is stored on the
>   heap, regardless of whether it's
>   declared within a reference type or a
>   value type. There is only one slot in
>   total no matter how many instances are
>   created. (There don't need to be any
>   instances created for that one slot to
>   exist though.) Note that this heap is
>   separate from the normal garbage
>   collected heap - it's known as a "high
>   frequency heap", and there's one per
>   application domain.

Stolen from [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4705/memory-in-net-what-goes-where/2/).

Comment: you mean that garbage collector is not working with static variables? so how it can dispose from memory?

Comment: so what is differnce between static class and static variables or method?

Comment: The whole point of static variables is that they exist for the lifetime of the appdomain, so by definition they will never be garbage collected - at least not until the appdomain/process exits. As for the different between static classes, static methods and static variables, they're completely different and the difference is C# 101. Static variables are "class level" - one instance of the variable is created across the appdomain, scoped according to the class it's in. Static methods are methods in a class that don't need to be called on an instance - they're basically global functions.

Comment: Static classes are classes that only contain static methods, and the compiler doesn't allow you to add regular methods or a constructor or derive from it. A static class is really just a namespace mechanism to put global functions in.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good overview of the various "loader heaps", of which the high frequency heap is one example, in this [excellent MSDN article on .Net runtime internals](https://web.archive.org/web/20140724084944/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx).

From that article:

> Frequently accessed artifacts like MethodTables, MethodDescs, FieldDescs, and Interface  Maps get allocated on a HighFrequencyHeap, while less frequently accessed data  structures, such as EEClass and ClassLoader and its lookup tables, get allocated on a LowFrequencyHeap. The StubHeap hosts stubs that facilitate code access security (CAS), COM wrapper calls, and P/Invoke.

Comment: Ugh, why can MS treat article URLs like they should be treated, as permanent resources. Will they ever learn? Fixed thanks to Internet Archive. Please consider a donation! www.archive.org

Comment: Or maybe [this](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/a/7/3a7fa450-1f33-41f7-9e6d-3aa95b5a6aea/MSDNMagazineMay2005en-us.chm) (warning: .chm inside).

Comment: @codekaizen: unfortunately, webarchive is currently banned in Russia.

Answer (score -2):

The point of the high-frequency heap is so that objects that will be frequently accessed are stored close to each other. This minimizes the working set of the process.

Comment: This doesn't really sound correct, in terms of the CLR, anyway.